# Android: How to inflate different layout from different buttons?

Tags: android, android-layout

I trying to do making something tabs but using button.

but each time I click on button it add me a row.
I want it to change the all layout to another..

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button btn1;
Button btn2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(switchListener);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(switchListener);

}

private OnClickListener switchListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.MyScrollView);

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.MyLinearLayout);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater
                .from(getApplicationContext());

        if (btn1 == v) {

            View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.firstview, null);

            ll.addView(v1);

        } else {

            View v2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.secondview, null);

            ll.addView(v2);
        }

    }
};
```

}

and here my Main XML file

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Layout 1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Layout 2" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/MyScrollView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/MyLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</TableRow>
```

and here my other two layouts that I want to inflate

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="First View"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>
```

and the second

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Second View"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>
```

Comment: Remove already added view before add another view. like: ll.removeAllViews()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make match parent your `tableview`.

and now do below on your code:-

```
   if(ll.getChildCount() > 0) {
       ll.removeAllViews(); 
   }

   if (btn1 == v) {

        View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.firstview, null);

        ll.addView(v1);

    } else {

        View v2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.secondview, null);

        ll.addView(v2);
    }
```

the problem is you are just adding child on layout one by one so you need to remove first then add into layout so try above code.

Answer (score 0):

before adding views to your ll linear layout check, as

```
if(ll.getChildCount() > 0) {
    ll.removeAllViews(); 
}
```

then perform:

```
ll.addView(view) v1 or v2 as required.
```

Comment: also explain your answer